# How to use SSO with SAML2.0

Tags: single-sign-on

we have a web application(Say wA) developed in java and we need to provide SSO login from client web application(Say WB) to WA and the requirement is to do with Okta-(SAML 2.0).

Currently im having the Idp mnetadatak, IDP Single Sign-On URL and Identity Provider Issuer link  created from okta

Anybody please help me on this issue , what things to do in my application side to provide SSO login felicity. how to listen SSO request from my APP (WA).
Thanks and regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you would like to add SAML support directly into your application (as opposed to including it for example in reverse proxy such as Apache or IIS), you can use either [Spring SAML](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/pdf/spring-security-saml-reference.pdf) (with minimal Spring configuration in case you don't use Spring Security already) or [OpenAM's Fedlet](http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/dev-guide/index/chap-fedlet-java.html).

Spring SAML enables applications to act as a SAML 2.0 Service Provider by initializing web single sign-on towards IDP (Okta) and accepting and validating response (SAML 2.0 Assertion) sent back from Okta.

Good approach to implement Spring SAML is to start with the [quick start guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html) which helps you create SAML 2.0 integration with a public SAML 2.0 Identity Provider, then change the IDP to Okta and then integrate the result into your application.

It is also possible to build SAML 2.0 support from scratch (using [OpenSAML](https://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.shibboleth.net%2Fconfluence%2Fdisplay%2FOpenSAML%2FHome&ei=OIi7U8zPLPSq4gTqkIDACw&usg=AFQjCNGFNKA-wzpYIcCseK0M4aNKcKr57g&sig2=2hsUvlFk51a6U0qa6jKEiw&bvm=bv.70138588,d.bGE) library), but significant knowledge of the protocol is needed for it to be done securely.

Some application servers also include SAML support (WebLogic, WebSphere, JBoss with its PicketLink library), but such configuration is of course not portable.

Comment: Thanks alot Vladimír Schäfer

Comment: My pleasure. If you're happy with the answer, please accept it so that the question is marked as answered.

Comment: hi Vladimir ,  i given entityIdentity as my website adress and generated metadata, then i added in SSOCIRCLE and it is showing error-Certificate found in Signature or KeyDescriptor under element "EntityDescriptor" is not trusted.

Comment: Is the error coming from SSO Circle or from Spring SAML? If from SSO Circle then generate your metadata without the digital signature as is described in the quick start guide, or remove the signature by hand before importing it to SSO Circle.

Comment: thanks, Error was coming from SpringSAMAL , i tried the above solution  and now error showing in SSO Circle Error occurred Reason: Unable to do Single Sign On or Federation.

Comment: Then revert to the configuration you had earlier which was working for you, please enable the debug logging (the Spring SAML manual contains details in chapter 5.5) and attach the resulting log and the Spring configuration to your question. You might want to open a new question as this is unrelated to your original question.

Comment: okay. can u please tell where is the file entityID_sp.xml located

Comment: There's no such file bundled in Spring SAML. If you generated your metadata from UI and the suggested configuration points you to this file, you will need to create the file yourself with metadata presented to you in the Spring SAML UI.

Comment: A metadata file referred to with classpath:security/idp.xml needs to go to WEB-INF/classes/security/idp.xml in your WAR file, or src/main/resources/security in your project (when using Maven). The usage of metadata and importing, including configuration of Spring, is explained in chapter 6.2 of the Spring SAML manual.

Comment: thanx Vladmir, i have created the the metadata and added in SSO circle. when im clicking into the "Initialize Single Sign-On" it is redirecting to the link "Location="baseURL/saml/SingleLogout/alias/localhost" saying invalid resource. actually what should i do in my application side to configure.. please clarify if im going in the wrong direction

Comment: If you still wish to get this working, I'd recommend you start all over, checkout the SAML library and carefully follow the quick start guide step by step, it will get you to the result. You can check here to see how the application looks and behaves when configured properly http://saml-federation.appspot.com/